# WebClient DownloadFileTaskAsync does not call ProgressChanged in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have following controller's action

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoDownload(string[] files)
{
   ...
   _netClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, ev) =>
   {
      Debug.WriteLine($"Progress: {ev.ProgressPercentage}");
   };

   await _netClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(file, location);

   ...
}
```

Seems that `Debug.WriteLine` line is never called. Why ?

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me. Did you put a breakpoint at `Debug.WriteLine` to see if it hits it?

Comment: Yes, I tried and breakpoint is never reached. Don’t know why. Did you try in dot net core with `Task<IActionResult>`?

Comment: This uses `Console.WriteLine`, but it shows that it's definitely calling the event handler: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RjTUIU

Comment: I tried locally too in [RoslynPad](https://roslynpad.net/) (targetting .NET Core).

Comment: I know you're a pro but it's possible that anyone forget to do simple things. Maybe you're in release mode. In this case `Debug.WriteLine` won't work.

Comment: @MasLoo I’m in debug mode